# Как настроить фильтр в админке django?

Tags: python, django

Использую модуль django MPTT, при указании фильтра выводит записи только текущего уровня дерева, если у текущего узла дерева есть дочерние узлы у которых есть записи, то он их не выводит.

```
class Section(MPTTModel):
    section_text = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название раздела', max_length=100)
    parent = TreeForeignKey(verbose_name='Родительский Раздел', to='self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

class Question(models.Model):
    section = models.ForeignKey(Section,verbose_name='Родительский раздел')
    question_text = HTMLField(verbose_name='Описание вопроса')
```

admin.py

```
class QuestionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_filter =(
        ('section', TreeRelatedFieldListFilter),
    )
```

Например имеется такое дерево

[image]

К узлу уровня 3 привязаны записи из Question, если выбрать узлы уровня 1 или 2, то записи узла 3 не выводятся, если выбрать уровень 3 то записи отображаются, т.е. отображаются записи только текущего узла, если у текущего узла есть дочерние узлы уровня ниже, то записи принадлежащие им не отображаются.

Comment: По всем признакам это баг. Я [сообщил о проблеме](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/579), но мейнтейнеры что-то не очень расторопны в последнее время. Можете пока воспользоваться [сборкой](http://gornostaev.su/media/files/django_mptt-0.8.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl) (wheel) [моего форка](https://github.com/TheDeadOne/django-mptt). Правда, это быстрый фикс, не проверял, что он всегда и везде будет работать хорошо.

Comment: Мой PR наконец смерджили, в версии 0.10.0 этой проблемы уже не будет.